# mysql - adding/concatenating text values within a SELECT clause

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in MySQL to concatenate text to values using a SELECT statement? (like in Oracle)

For example, in Oracle you can write something like this:

```
SQL> select 'The Year is '|| year, 'The month is '|| month from time where rownum < 2;

'THEYEARIS'||YEAR
----------------------------------------------------
'THEMONTHIS'||MONTH
-----------------------------------------------------
The Year is 2009
The month is 1
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT Concat(vend_name, ' (', vend_country, ')')
FROM vendors
ORDER BY vend_name;
```

Read this tutorial:

http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Concatenating_Fields.htm

Answer (score 4):

There is a [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function in mysql.

```
select concat('The Year is ', year), concat('The month is ', month) from time where rownum < 2;
```